# Publishing git subtree of directory which is in gitignore

Tags: git

Say I have a directory called 'dist' - I don't want to track changes to this directory, so I have added it to gitignore.

However, I want to publish the contents of this directory to another git repo/remote, and I do this using:

```
git subtree push --prefix dist my-other-remote master
```

the problem seems to be that since I have gitignore the dist directory, when I call the git subtree command, git doesn't see any changes to push, even if I add a new file to the dist directory.

Is there any way around this, or should I rethink this?

Comment: Seems like maybe I should just create a whole new git repo in the dist directory? instead of using git subtree?